# Function that display a file type

Tags: c, unix, ls

I would like to code the unix system `ls`.

But I am a newbie and got a problem when I want to get the type...
My program display random type value.
What argument do I have to send to my function ?

Oh, and I don't want to use any global value

Here is my function:

```
void    my_get_type(const mode, struct direct *d)
{
  if (S_ISREG(mode))
    my_printf("-");
  if (S_ISDIR(mode))
    my_printf("d");
}
```

There is my main with the argument I am sending:

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  DIR           *dir;
  struct direct *d;
  struct stat   buffer;
  char          *directory;
  int           j;
  int           i;

  j = 0;
  i = 0;
  dir = opendir(".");
  if (dir == NULL)
    {
      my_printf("no directory");
      return (0);
    }
  while (argv[i])
    {
      if (argv[i][j] == '-')
        {
          ++j;
          if (argv[i][j] == 'l')
            {
              while (d = readdir(dir))
                {
                  my_get_type(buffer.st_mode, d);
                  //my_get_droits();                                            
                  //my_get_size();                                              
                  //user soon                                            
                  //4096 ?                                                      
                  //my_get_time();                                              
                  my_printf("%s\n", d->d_name);
                }
            }
        }
      else
        ++i;
    }
  while (d = readdir(dir))
    my_printf("%s ", d->d_name);
  closedir(dir);
}
```

and if you have any other tips for a beginner like me... that would make me happy ^^

Comment: Call stat() on the file to get the file mode from struct stat.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_get_type(buffer.st_mode, d);
```

`buffer` is uninitialized here.